# Partition/split a string by character set in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, split

How can I separate different character sets in my string? For example, if I had these charsets:

```
[a-z]
[A-Z]
[0-9]
[\s]
{everything else}
```

And this input:

```
thisISaTEST***1234pie
```

Then I want to separate the different character sets, for example, if I used a newline as the separating character:

```
this
IS
a
TEST
***
1234
pie
```

I've tried this regex, with a positive lookahead:

```
'thisISaTEST***1234pie'.gsub(/(?=[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[0-9]+|[\s]+)/, "\n")
```

But apparently the `+`s aren't being greedy, because I'm getting:

```
t
h
# (snip)...
S
T***
1
# (snip)...
e
```

I snipped out the irrelevant parts, but as you can see each character is counting as its own charset, except the `{everything else}` charset.

How can I do this? It does not necessarily have to be by regex. Splitting them into an array would work too.

Comment: (sorry for the terrible title; I couldn't think of anything better. please do edit if you understand what I want and you can think of a better one. `:)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficult part is to match whatever that does not match the rest of the regex. Forget about that, and think of a way that you can mix the non-matching parts together with the matching parts.

```
"thisISaTEST***1234pie"
.split(/([a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+|\s+)/).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["this", "IS", "a", "TEST", "***", "1234", "pie"]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ASCII character set, apart from alphanumerics and space, there are thirty-two "punctuation" characters, which are matched with the property construct `\p{punct}`.

To split your string into sequences of a single category, you can write

```
str = 'thisISaTEST***1234pie'
p str.scan(/\G(?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+|\s+|[\p{punct}]+)/)
```

**output**

```
["this", "IS", "a", "TEST", "***", "1234", "pie"]
```

Alternatively, if your string contains characters outside the ASCII set, you could write the whole thing in terms of properties, like this

```
p str.scan(/\G(?:\p{lower}+|\p{upper}+|\p{digit}+|\p{space}|[^\p{alnum}\p{space}]+)/)
```

Comment: I don't want just punctuation though, I want any other character to work as well.

Comment: I tried to explain that all that remains after alphanumerics and space is the punctuation characters (and control characters). Of course that doesn't work if your data contains characters outside the ASCII set.

Answer (score 0):

Here a two solutions.

**[String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression**

```
str = "thisISa\n TEST*$*1234pie"
```

```
r = /[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+|\s+|[^a-zA-Z\d\s]+/
str.scan r
  #=> ["this", "IS", "a", "\n ", "TEST", "*$*", "1234", "pie"]
```

Because of `^` at the beginning of `[^a-zA-Z\d\s]` that character class matches any character *other than* letters (lower and upper case), digits and whitespace.

**Use [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when)<sup>1</sup>**

First, a helper method:

```
def type(c)
  case c
  when /[a-z]/ then 0
  when /[A-Z]/ then 1
  when /\d/    then 2
  when /\s/    then 3
  else              4
  end
end
```

For example,

```
type "f"   #=> 0
type "P"   #=> 1
type "3"   #=> 2
type "\n"  #=> 3
type "*"   #=> 4
```

Then

```
str.each_char.slice_when { |c1,c2| type(c1) != type(c2) }.map(&:join)
  #=> ["this", "IS", "a", "TEST", "***", "1234", "pie"]
```

<sup>1. `slich_when` made its debut in Ruby v2.4.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Non-word, non-space chars can be covered with `[^\w\s]`, so:

```
"thisISaTEST***1234pie".scan /[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+|\s+|[^\w\s]+/
#=> ["this", "IS", "a", "TEST", "***", "1234", "pie"]
```

Comment: @sawa - `_` is a word char but it doesn't fit into any of those groups so it's not clear where it belongs.

Comment: It clearly belongs to the OP's `everything else`, but it does not fit anywhere in your regex.

Comment: @sawa to fit the `_` into `everything else`: `(?:[^\w\s]|_)`